# HttpContext.Current.Session seems to be reset when embedded in Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, sharepoint, httpcontext

We have an internal ASP.NET web application - it's hosted by IIS but embedded into Sharepoint via Web Parts. It needed some tweaks, so I made the tweaks and tested it all on IIS Express via Visual Studio; all is well.

I've come to deploy the app onto a newly built UAT server (since this app didn't have one existing), and there I run into problems. Certain data is stored in `HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"]` - for example a drop down control might be set to a particular value which is then stored in the session to persist across page refresh. The problem is that *when embedded in Sharepoint*, that persistence doesn't seem to work (and so the application behaves strangely). When you access the application directly by navigating to its address, everything is fine.

Now; the production Web App does **not** have this problem, even when embedded into the UAT Sharepoint site. That being the case, I'm pretty certain that the problem lies in how I've configured IIS. I can't see any difference between the UAT and Prod servers though, so I'm lost for ideas about where to go from here.

What could cause the application to "forget" its session state in this manner? Particularly only when embedded into Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the below code in your web.config file:

```
<pages enableSessionState="true" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*******" asyncTimeout="7">
```

and

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
</modules>
```

You could refer the below thread for more detail:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83784/session-and-httpcontext-not-available-in-web-part
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/3145fd29-2315-42f7-8f9d-cf6d52dc3c95/enabling-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: thanks - unfortunately I've tried those already to no success.

Comment: @DanScally is your applications are hosted in the same environment or different?

Comment: the Web App is hosted on an entirely different server to the Sharepoint site.